# How to use Struts 2 annotation with XML configuration together

Tags: java, struts2

Recently I did try to configure [**Struts 2 annotation**] with [**XML config**] together, although the XML always overrides the annotations config. It is possible to use them together? Or no way?

Comment: You can you any configuration that you provide. Struts2 pick up a configuration it's looking for, the way it's implemented. This is unclear what are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

You can use both. For using annotation you need the [Convention Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html). And you need to mention in web.xml that you are using annotations like this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>package</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

This [official struts site](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-annotations.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: This configuration is for enable development mode, to show messages clearly to developer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add anything to the web.xml if you meet the following:

The convention plugin searches for packages with names: **struts, struts2, action, actions** and then searches all their subpackages for classes that implement `Action` (or extends `ActionSupport` which implements `Action`), and classes whose names end with "Action".
See more:
https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/#introduction

It will find these classes automatically and search for annotations inside them.